# Why can I seek .mp3 files JWPlayer?

Tags: html, html5-audio, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I am using JWPlayer to play .mp3 files on my website, however I am having trouble with the behaviour of the player with links from my download system.

Visit this test page I have created http://bit.ly/TLwEHc

The first player which contains a link to a real directory with a file and this plays just fine, however on the second player which contains a link to a script which generates a file does not. 
I have tried replicating the headers in the generated file but it still has not made a difference.

Could anyone tell me what could be causing this behaviour and how I could resolve this?

Comment: Your server side script most likely does not support range requests.

Comment: @t.niese thats a good point. I've now changed the first players url to a link located on the same server. It seems to be the same issue so I don't think it has to do with range requests.

Comment: @t.niese actually you could be right here, in my generated links they appear as 206 Partial Content. This could be the problem, I believe this has something to do with the Content-Range header which is not present in the generated links.

Comment: Indeed, the Content-Range header needs to be supported in order to seek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [link](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/6062337-using-content-range-http-header-for-streaming) to see that `Content-Range header` needs to be supported in order to seek.

I also checked with one more url and audio works fine and seeks correctly

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/F9wVx/13/)